# On branch main Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'

Tags: error-handling

when i want to do git commit . thats time i face this problem .
this problem come almost every time when i want to do git commit.
please tell how remove this problem on my computer

Comment: i think you don't any change your code ! so seeing on you computer

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem. It just means that your local copy of the branch is up to date with the remote (probably on a server somewhere).